# short definition for 'Chavrusa'

Tags: words, torah-study, chavrusa

I'm looking for a way to accurately describe what a chavrusa (in a yeshiva setting) is to a non-Jew. I'm ideally looking for a one or two line description.

Basically the shorter the better, but it should accurately describe it to someone from a completely different background.

Comment: "Study-partner" wouldn't suffice?

Comment: @yEz not really. The picture that usually generates is a lot different than a chavrusa.

Comment: It would be really hard to explain to someone what a Chavrusa is unless they understand what a Yeshiva Gedola is.

Answer (score 3):

A study-partner with whom one analyzes and debates the subject matter of study, usually pertaining to a particular text. Chavrusas are not just reading or reviewing together - they are jointly working out an understanding in a process that often involves challenging and argumentation.

Comment: Note also that Chavrusas often tackle new material in perpetration for lecture, not just reviewing for a test.

Comment: @DoubleAA that was what I meant when I said they are not just reviewing. Was that not clear?

Comment: Maybe substitute "learning partner" for study-partner. In common usage, "learning" refers to tackling new material while "study" tends to refer to mastering material previously learned.

Comment: @LN6595 Is there anything that connotes both? Because chavrusas often do both.